# Bootstrap datepicker resetting after reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

Bootstrap DatePicker is resetting to default date after page reload. If I don't reload the page I'm able to keep selected date

```html
<div class="form-group"> 
  <label>Action Date </label>
  <div class='input-group date' id='dpServiceDate'> 
    <input type='text' class="form-control" id="actionDate" name="actionDate" /> 
    <span class="input-group-addon"> 
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> 
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#dpServiceDate').datetimepicker({
    defaultDate: "@Model.ActionDate.Date.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")",
    format: 'MM-DD-YYYY',
    maxDate: moment().subtract(1, 'days')
  }).on('dp.change', function(e) {
    location.href = "/XYZ/DashBoard/Index?Id=" + @Model.ClientId + "&ActionDate=" + $("#actionDate").val();
  })
});
```

Comment: <div class="form-group">
 <label>Action Date </label>
 <div class='input-group date' id='dpServiceDate'>
 <input type='text' class="form-control" id="actionDate" name="actionDate" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
             </span>
                    </div>
                </div>

Comment: Firstly, please use the `edit` link under your question to add more information to it. Secondly, this sounds like expected behaviour. HTML does not store state, so as soon as you change page (or reload the current one) any changes you made will be lost. You need to save them somewhere, then load them again

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm sending selected date to model and after page reload setting date from model, so ideally it should keep selected value during reload.

Comment: Set a cookie, use the cookie as the default value.

Comment: @TRose Can you please provide some example as i'm new to this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17521905/5000465

Answer (score 0):

Add **`useCurrent: false`**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dpServiceDate').datetimepicker({
        defaultDate: "@Model.ActionDate.Date.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")",
        format: 'MM-DD-YYYY',
        useCurrent: false,
        maxDate: moment().subtract(1, 'days')
    }).on('dp.change', function(e) {
        location.href = "/XYZ/DashBoard/Index?Id=" + @Model.ClientId + "&ActionDate=" + $("#actionDate").val();
    })
});
```